# Square on icon on Wordpress admin bar

Tags: wordpress, icons, themes, admin

I want to check status of my wordpress because I have see the error on admin bar in WordPress (see image) and I don’t know how solve it. At the moment I have see square on admin bar. I have a multi site WordPress.

Can I reinstall latest Wordpress with botton in admin? Update multi site? What do you think about? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Did you check your [browser developer tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) for errors? And [WP_DEBUG](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wp-debug?sort=frequent&pageSize=50)?

Comment: No errors on wp_debug

Comment: I have solved... Load CSS asynchronously and Minify CSS have a problem with my configuration... I'm checking...

Answer (score 0):

If you have CSS customization such as

```
*{
font-family: "Poppins", Sans-serif !important;}
```

The WordPress admin bar uses icon fonts (like Dashicons) to display its icons. When you override the font family for all elements, including those icons, they can't render properly and often show up as squares or other placeholder characters.

Removing this worked for me.